# Contributors missing from author dropdown

Tags: user-roles

I have a problem with Quick Edit post functions.

When I add new users as Contributors, they don't appear in author dropdown list.

I am using *Role Scoper* plugin for some roles. But I tried to deactivate plugin and it doesn't help.

Can someone help me with advice?

Comment: downvoted as there are no details to help do anything more than guessing

Answer (score 0):

My advice is to read the Codex regarding user roles and capabilities.

Contributors cannot publish posts.

Edit: I am able to successfully add new users with the 'contributor' role, and select them from the dropdown as the author of a post, which is what I now realize you're having issues with. So something is definitely wrong if this is not working for you. Disregard my earlier advice, because it is not relevant to your problem.

Comment: You are wrong. Contributors, by default, has the capability os "edit_posts". This capability gives access to Add New post, so a contributor can create posts. What a contributor can not do is publish the post. Once the post have been published by a editor or administrator, the contributor can not longer edit the post or change the status.

Comment: You are correct, I meant to say that they could not 'publish' posts. (I edited my answer to reflect this.) I thought this may be what the OP was unable to do, but perhaps I'm mistaken.

Comment: @cybmeta Please add that as clarification to the question. Thanks.

Comment: This is not an answer, it should be a comment "Read the manual, it works for me" is not an answer.

Comment: @Jesse SkyShabs answer is that contributors cannot publish posts, which the top comment on this answer says is incorrect. It's possible for answers to be incorrect as also noted in the edit