# How to force the Author Dropdown to display in Quick/Bulk edit?

Tags: author, dropdown

I believe this issue is a bug with the latest version of WP on multisite (I've reported it) but until they fix it I really need a simple solution. I have multiple authors (Administrator and Editor permissions) on a subsite that we have migrated from our previous site. The author dropdown works as expected when creating a new or editing a post but does not display when using Bulk/Quick edit. I have over 1,000 articles that we have imported and I need to assign them to the correct authors. The idea of having the edit each article to achieve this is less than desirable. In researching here I found this article which is close: [How to force listing contributors in authors dropdown menu](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/269153/how-to-force-listing-contributors-in-authors-dropdown-menu) but all I really need to do is force the author dropdown menu to display in Bulk/Quick edit. Any thoughts or ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

After digging through many bug reports I found a solution to the issue I was facing. The problem I was having is related to a new feature in 6.0 for sites with over 10K user accounts which automatically disables the author dropdown in Bulk/Quick edit. I'm not sure how they decided that was a good idea but se la vie. Here is the solution they offered which I tested and it works as expected.

Add the following code snippet to your theme or in my case a muplugin:

```
add_filter( 'wp_is_large_user_count', '__return_false' );
```

And as they say in Dublin, "Bob's your uncle!"